# Compute $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty }{\sum _{k=1}^n\left(k\binom nk\binom nk(k!)k^{n-k}\right)}\frac{1}{n^{n+1}}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty }{\sum _{k=1}^n\left(k\binom nk\binom nk(k!)k^{n-k}\right)}\frac{1}{n^{n+1}}$

I'm trying by using squeeze law , but eventually I'm stumped.
I need help !

Comment: it doesn't go to $\infty $ ?

Comment: I omit the $\frac{1}{n^{n+1}}$..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your sum is greater or equal than the central term which goes to $+\infty$:
$$\frac{1}{n^{n+1}}\sum _{k=1}^n\left(k\binom nk\binom nk(k!)k^{n-k}\right)\geq \binom{n}{n/2}^2((n/2)!)(n/2)^{n/2+1-(n+1)}=C''\cdot \frac{4^n}{e^{n/2}\sqrt{n}}\to +\infty,$$
where we used 
$$\binom{n}{n/2}\sim C\cdot \frac{2^n}{\sqrt{n}}\quad\mbox{and}\quad (n/2)!\sim C'\cdot \frac{n^{(n+1)/2}}{(2e)^{n/2}}.$$